# Jetpack Compose Combo box with dropdown

Tags: android, combobox, android-jetpack-compose

In order to practice Jetpack Compose I wanted to create a MultiComboBox component for later use. It's basically standard ComboBox that allows to pick multiple options. Something like below:
[image: How should it look like]

I did prepare a piece of code that IMO should work fine and generally it does, but there's one case when it doesn't and I cannot figure it out what's wrong.

Here's my code:

```
data class ComboOption(
    override val text: String,
    val id: Int,
) : SelectableOption

interface SelectableOption {
    val text: String
}

@Composable
fun MultiComboBox(
    labelText: String,
    options: List<ComboOption>,
    onOptionsChosen: (Set<ComboOption>) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    selectedIds: Set<Int> = emptySet(),
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    // when no options available, I want ComboBox to be disabled
    val isEnabled by rememberUpdatedState { options.isNotEmpty() } 
    var currentlySelected by remember(options, selectedIds) {
        mutableStateOf(options.filter { it.id in selectedIds }.toSet())
    }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                expanded = !expanded
                if (!expanded) {
                    onOptionsChosen(currentlySelected)
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        val selectedSummary = when (selectedIds.size) {
            0 -> ""
            1 -> options.first { it.id == selectedIds.first() }.text
            else -> "Wybrano ${selectedIds.size}"
        }
        TextField(
            enabled = isEnabled(),
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedSummary,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(text = labelText) },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
                onOptionsChosen(currentlySelected)
            },
        ) {
            for (option in options) {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = {
                        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                            Checkbox(
                                checked = option in currentlySelected,
                                onCheckedChange = { newCheckedState ->
                                    if (newCheckedState) {
                                        currentlySelected += option
                                    } else {
                                        currentlySelected -= option
                                    }
                                },
                            )
                            Text(text = option.text)
                        }
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        val isChecked = option in currentlySelected
                        if (isChecked) {
                            currentlySelected -= option
                        } else {
                            currentlySelected += option
                        }
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I pick options and then dismiss the combo by clicking somewhere outside of it - it works fine. The problem is with `onExpandedChange`. `currentlySelected` inside of that lambda is always the same as first value of `selectedIds`. So for example, when no options are preselected it always calls `onOptionsChosen` with empty set, hence regardless of what I select - it always sets empty value. Any ideas why it happens an how can it be fixed?

Comment: How do you import `menuAnchor`?  Mine says unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@Composable
fun MultiComboBox(
    labelText: String,
    options: List<ComboOption>,
    onOptionsChosen: (List<ComboOption>) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    selectedIds: List<Int> = emptyList(),
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    // when no options available, I want ComboBox to be disabled
    val isEnabled by rememberUpdatedState { options.isNotEmpty() }
    var selectedOptionsList  = remember { mutableStateListOf<Int>()}

    //Initial setup of selected ids
    selectedIds.forEach{
        selectedOptionsList.add(it)
    }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                expanded = !expanded
                if (!expanded) {
                    onOptionsChosen(options.filter { it.id in selectedOptionsList }.toList())
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        val selectedSummary = when (selectedOptionsList.size) {
            0 -> ""
            1 -> options.first { it.id == selectedOptionsList.first() }.text
            else -> "Wybrano ${selectedOptionsList.size}"
        }
        TextField(
            enabled = isEnabled(),
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedSummary,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(text = labelText) },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
                onOptionsChosen(options.filter { it.id in selectedOptionsList }.toList())
            },
        ) {
            for (option in options) {
                
                //use derivedStateOf to evaluate if it is checked
                var checked = remember {
                    derivedStateOf{option.id in selectedOptionsList}
                }.value

                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = {
                        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                            Checkbox(
                                checked = checked,
                                onCheckedChange = { newCheckedState ->
                                    if (newCheckedState) {
                                        selectedOptionsList.add(option.id)
                                    } else {
                                        selectedOptionsList.remove(option.id)
                                    }
                                },
                            )
                            Text(text = option.text)
                        }
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        if (!checked) {
                            selectedOptionsList.add(option.id)
                        } else {
                            selectedOptionsList.remove(option.id)
                        }
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]